# Sencha Touch tabPanel tabbar dynamic images

Tags: tabs, sencha-touch, extjs

In my application i am having a tabPanel. The title and icons of the tabs need to be dynamic. I am getting this data from the server. But i couldn't find any way which can load icons from a external source URL. I used the iconCls property with my custom class as .tab{-webkit-mask-box-image: url("SomeHttpURL")} but this is also static. How do i make SomeHttpURL a placeholder which replaces with the URL i am getting from server at the runtime?

Tarun Sharma.

Answer (score 1):

In your css:

```
.x-tab img.your_icon_name .x-button img.x-icon-mask.your_icon_name{
    -webkit-mask-image:url("SomeHttpURL");
}
```

In your panel code:

> iconCls: 'your_icon_name',